# How to generate same set of permutation using sample() in R?

Tags: r, sample

I am using sample() function for generating radnom data in R.

```
 x<-1:12
 sample(x)
 [1] 10  9  4  3 12 11  8  6  1  2  5  7

 x<-1:12
 sample(x)
 [1]  2  6  8 12 10 11  1  3  5  7  9  4
```

I get different set in two different call. Is there any way to generate the same set of records?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `set.seed(1)` (or any number) for that

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(x)
 [1]  4  5  6  9  2  7 10 12  3  1 11  8
```

Comment: If you really want to be safe, you can wrap the seed & sample together in braces  `x <- {set.seed(1); sample(12)}`

Comment: So long as you set the same seed every time you start the session or run the code, you'll always get reproducible samples.